# How do I wait for an asynchronous function to finish correctly (flutter, dart)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, asynchronous

I want to build a screen for a flutter app which shows a camera preview. To achieve this I have to initialize the camera asynchronously. This leads to an exception because I access the camera before it is initialized. I work around that with using a try-catch block. But this strikes me as a dirty solution. Is there a better one? I am developing on windows for android. here is my full code for that screen. I marked the points of interest with line comments.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

class CameraPreviewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraPreviewPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CameraPreviewPage> createState() => _CameraPreviewPageState();
}

class _CameraPreviewPageState extends State<CameraPreviewPage> {
  late List<CameraDescription> _cameraDescriptions;
  late CameraController _cameraController; //Here I declare the camera object which throws an "late not inizialized" exception

//this function inizializes the object but asynchronously
  void initCamera() async {
    _cameraDescriptions = await availableCameras();
    _cameraController = CameraController(
      _cameraDescriptions[0],
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      enableAudio: false,
    );
    await _cameraController.initialize().then((value) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint(e);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initCamera();
    super.initState();
  }

//in this build function the Exception occurs.
// Wrapping the "CameraPreview(_cameraController)," line in a try catch gives me working but ugly(?) code
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    try {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            CameraPreview(_cameraController),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      return const SizedBox();
    }
  }
}
```

I am pretty new to asynchronous programming and to flutter/dart itself. If this question gets answered somewhere else plsease lead me there because I couldn't find it on google/youtube.

I tried the FutureBuilder Widget but it did not work correctly, maybe I didn't understand it and sadly I lost the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `initState` itself is not an async method and cannot await your `initCamera`. So your `initCamera` is executing while your `build` method is already being called.

And then your `_cameraController` is not initialized yet, but used inside of your build method.

To fix this, you can conditionally show different widgets depending on a state bool, or use a `FutureBuilder` widget instead.

Your state class when using a bool:

```dart
class _CameraPreviewPageState extends State<CameraPreviewPage> {
  late List<CameraDescription> _cameraDescriptions;
  late CameraController _cameraController; //Here I declare the camera object which throws an "late not inizialized" exception
  bool _initialized = false;

//this function inizializes the object but asynchronously
  void initCamera() async {
    _cameraDescriptions = await availableCameras();
    _cameraController = CameraController(
      _cameraDescriptions[0],
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      enableAudio: false,
    );
    await _cameraController.initialize().then((value) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {
        _initialized = true;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint(e);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initCamera();
    super.initState();
  }

//in this build function the Exception occurs.
// Wrapping the "CameraPreview(_cameraController)," line in a try catch gives me working but ugly(?) code
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    try {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            if(_initialized) CameraPreview(_cameraController),
            if(!_initialized) Text("loading..."),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      return const SizedBox();
    }
  }
}
```